# Error launching Javafx chart as an instance from the main method

Tags: java, charts, javafx

Am having an issue getting Javafx charts to lauch from another class. When an instance of the class is created in the Main method such as:

```
Charts c = new Charts();
```

The following code results in the following runtime error

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class Charts
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$7.run(LauncherImpl.java:791)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:118)
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:241)
    at Charts.<init>(Charts.java:50)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application Charts
```

Please can anyone help to rectify the situation? I believe the issue may be due to using launch() in the Charts method without supplying specific arguments.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Charts extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        // defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        // creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(
                xAxis, yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        // defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        // populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public Charts() {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not a supported way of launching a JavaFX Application. (I can't tell you the exact details of why it is failing without the stack trace.) The `launch` method will instantiate a new instance of your `Application` class for you, start the JavaFX subsystem, and execute the `start(...)` method. You should consider the `start(...)` method the entry point in your application (in fact, in Java 8, you can launch an `Application` subclass from the command line even if it has no `main(...)` method at all).

If you want to make your `Charts` class reusable, so it can be launched from a variety of places, either make it a subclass of something that can be placed in a `Scene`, or give it an accessor method for such an object. Subclasses of `Application` have a specific function as the "startup class" of a JavaFX application.

E.g.

```
public class Charts {
    private Parent content ;

    public Charts() {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");

        // ... etc etc

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

        content = new StackPane();
        content.getChildren().add(lineChart);
    }

    public Parent getContent() {
        return content ;
    }
}
```

And then you can create application classes which use this with

```
public class MyChartApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("My chart app");
        Charts c = new Charts();
        Scene scene = new Scene(c.getContent(), 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

You could add some utility methods such as

```
public Scene createScene() {
    return new Scene(content, 800, 600);
}
```

and

```
public void configureStage(Stage stage) {
    stage.setScene(createScene());
}
```

to the `Charts` class if you want/need.

Then (of course) your `start(...)` method could be reduced to

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    new Charts().configureStage(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Just to add, `Application#launch()` creates a separate JavaFX thread and only one instance is allowed per VM, so calling the launch inside the constructor will throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once`

Comment: If the OP is using `Charts` as the main application entry, sure. But I understood he had some other entry point: `public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) { new Charts();}}`. But maybe I am missing something. Anyway... this is not the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still having problems with implementation and getting the code to run when it is not from the main class.

Comment: The point is that if your class is a subclass of `Application`, it *is* your "main class". Any code you want to invoke from another class should be in a class that is not a subclass of `Application`. (Don't invoke `launch` from anywhere else, for example.) If you are still having trouble with that, either update your question or post a new one.